# If items are no longer in stock, display a different text? (Shopify)

Tags: php, api, shopify, shopify-api

I would like to resell a product even if we no longer have it in stock. Then we give a delivery time.

If the option "Continue selling when out of stock" is activated, the item is displayed, even if the quantity
is 0. Can I bypass this and display a different text if the quantity is 0 ... like "Not in stock, but will be
ordered for you"? Is it possible to query the status of "Continue selling when out of stock"
via Liquid and then to compare the quantity and status?

Thanks
Marco

These settings indicate that the item is in stock ... I want to change that.
[image: Inventory - Continue selling when out of stock]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the 'php' tag and add a 'liquid' tag. Liquid is the templating language used by Shopify.

To answer your question, yes it is possible. The changes need to be added in the current active product template file. Default one is product-template.liquid

The liquid code for checking if a product's quantity is equal or less than 0 is

```
{% if current_variant.inventory_quantity <= 0 %}
    Do something.
{% endif %}
```

However, the above code will also be true for products with "Continue selling when out of stock" option **unticked**.

So if you want this to only be true for products that have quantity equal or less than 0 AND "Continue selling when out of stock" option **ticked** you can use this:

```
{% if current_variant.inventory_quantity <= 0 and product.available %}
    Do something.
{% endif %}
```

The above code will only work on products with quantity equal or less than 0 and is purchaseable, in other words, with "Continue selling when out of stock" option ticked.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I paste it into the page for testing, nothing happens. Do I need to supplement it with something?

Starting with the 'liquid' and still learning :)

Thanks